# Premature finalization of function return value

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I have a derived type `t_file` with a finalization routine `close` which simply writes "Finalization" to the screen.
There is also a function returning an instance of the type `t_file`.
The output of this program is

```
Finalization.
Finalization.
Just opened
     2000
Done.
```

I have two questions:

- Why does the finalization occur *before* the `Just opened` output?
- Why does the finalization occur *twice*?

My compiler is Intel(R) Visual Fortran Composer XE 2011 12.1.3526.2010.

Here is the code:

```
module m_file
    implicit none


    type t_file
        integer::iu=1000

        contains

        final::close
    end type

    contains

    function openFile() result(f)
        implicit none

        type(t_file)::f

        f%iu = 2000

    end function

    subroutine close(this)
        implicit none

        type(t_file)::this

        write(*,*) 'Finalization.'

    end subroutine

end module

program foo
    use m_file
    implicit none

    type(t_file)::f

    f = openFile()
    write(*,*) 'Just opened'
    write(*,*) f%iu

    write(*,*) 'Done.'    
    read(*,*)

end program
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour surprised me too.  I've been getting to grips with Fortran's new(-ish) OO features but haven't yet needed to write final procedures.  I think that I can provide an explanation, of sorts, for this behaviour.

On p282 of [Modern Fortran Explained](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_19?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=modern%20fortran%20explained&x=0&y=0&sprefix=modern%20fortran%20expl,aps,143) the authors write:

> When a finalizable object is about to cease to exist (for example, by
>   being deallocated or from execution of a `return` statement), the final
>   subroutine is invoked with the object as its actual argument.  This
>   also occurs when the object is passed to an intent `out` dummy
>   argument, or is the variable on the left-hand side of an intrinsic
>   assignment statement.  In the latter case, the final subroutine is
>   invoked after the expression on the right-hand side has been
>   evaluated, but before it is assigned to the variable.

It looks to me as if you are hitting both of the two cases mentioned in this paragraph. You get the first `Finalization` when the entity named `f` inside the function `openFile` is about to go out of scope on return from that function.

You get the second `Finalization` when the variable `f` in the program scope is used on the *lhs* of the assignment `f = openFile()`.

From all of this I conclude that you are not seeing premature finalisation of `f` in the program scope, but something subtly different.

I'm not entirely convinced that this is what is happening, and I cannot think of a good reason why the language's behaviour should be as it is.  I'm a bit surprised, now that I've looked into it, that you don't get a third `Finalization` message as the program ends and `f` goes out of scope.

With any luck a real Fortran guru will come past soon and enlighten us all.

Comment: I think your explanation is very good. I would also expect the third one. I think the design is logical, as you may need it in all those cases.

Comment: Unfortunately I wanted the finalization to close a file unit for me, so it had the behaviour of closing the unit before I'd even used it. I guess I can simply do without finalization.

Comment: On another note, in other parts of the full program, it actually worked fine and didn't finalize prematurely. I haven't yet been able to distill an example of that down though.

Comment: I think you are getting it wrong.  It would not close your file prematurely.

Comment: It would if instead of writing "Finalization" the final routine closed the file unit...

Comment: Gosh, I'm very late coming to this, but (and you probably know by nearly four years later): finalization doesn't occur for things when the program comes to an end.

Answer (score 0):

Minor correction to answer given by High Performance Mark: The first finalization is actually  the variable f in the program scope. This can be seen simply by having the final routine print this%iu and setting f%iu in the program scope to some arbitrary value.